# How to create highlight textview like Adobe Reader or Medium?

Tags: java, android, string, kotlin, textview

guys.
I need a little bit inspiration right here. I want to create an application that have a highlight feature, just like screenshot below. But, I don't have an idea how to do this. I think Spannable TextView only can't just help me. Do you have some idea?
Thank you.

[Example of highlight menu in Medium App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AB9b6.png)

Comment: have you tried `SpannableString`? and then setting `BackgroundColorSpan`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SpannableString](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html)

To highlight specific text use this method.

```
private void highlightString(String input) {
//Get the text from text view and create a spannable string
SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(mTextView.getText());
//Get the previous spans and remove them
BackgroundColorSpan[] backgroundSpans = spannableString.getSpans(0, spannableString.length(), BackgroundColorSpan.class);

for (BackgroundColorSpan span: backgroundSpans) {
    spannableString.removeSpan(span);
}

//Search for all occurrences of the keyword in the string
int indexOfKeyword = spannableString.toString().indexOf(input);

while (indexOfKeyword > 0) {
    //Create a background color span on the keyword
    spannableString.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.YELLOW), indexOfKeyword, indexOfKeyword + input.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

    //Get the next index of the keyword
    indexOfKeyword = spannableString.toString().indexOf(input, indexOfKeyword + input.length());
}

//Set the final text on TextView
mTextView.setText(spannableString);}
```